# Black screen at login

Tags: startup, background-process

In `/etc/profile.d/` I inserted the file `custom.sh` which reads:

```
~/.start/speakers.sh &
~/.start/vpn.sh &
```

As you can see, both files are run in the background. Why am I still experiencing, sometimes but not always, a black screen after I press login? When that happens, I don't see the desktop.

This morning, I had to turn off the computer the hard way, then boot again. This time no problem, the desktop appeared with the speakers connected and the VPN on.

I suspect that's because of `~/.start/vpn.sh &`, sometimes the command inside this file pauses for a (very) long time. What I don't understand is, why is this an issue? The file is run in the background.

My OS is Ubuntu LTS 22.04. More info:

`systemd-analyze blame | head` returns:

```
6.126s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.485s plymouth-quit-wait.service
1.223s apt-daily-upgrade.service
 903ms snapd.seeded.service
 617ms snapd.service
 534ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
 349ms gpu-manager.service
 313ms fwupd.service
 275ms systemd-resolved.service
 254ms systemd-timesyncd.service
```

`ls /usr/bin/*session` returns:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-run-session /usr/bin/gnome-session /usr/bin/gnome-session-custom-session /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `systemd-analyze blame | head` please? And the separately `ls /usr/bin/*session` also.

Comment: I replied in the OP, thank you.

Comment: Well you have multiple desktop environments installed but none I recognize as crashers. The final entry of your systemd-analyze indicates that the second shell that is executed has some kind of time delay in it. Did you create the .sh files yourself? Can you #  out the line with the timer and see if youj get a different boot result?

Comment: Yes I created all `.sh` files myself. I can comment out either line if you like, but since tthe system usually starts without problem, it may take a while for me to get back to you and say if there's any significant change.

Would you suggest any other way to run a script in the background, or in another thread?

Comment: I think your startup is OK but booting to a customised desktop environment always has it's problems. Which one are you actually booting to? Type `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and it will tell you.

Comment: The answer is `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME`

Comment: OK then that's the default, nothing to worry about. I think it's just a delay of some kind caused by your startup scripts.

Comment: Ok thanks, but in the end, we have no idea what's wrong with the system. A background script should not delay anything between logging in and accessing to the desktop.

Comment: What exactly is the order in which the folder `/etc/profile.d/` is run? Is it possible that the scripts in it are run too early? That must be the cause. I think I would solve my problem if I could run those scripts right after the desktop is shown.